# How to make songs start later on rhythmbox?

Tags: 12.04, configuration, rhythmbox

I want to make a couple of songs start playing after 30 seconds after the beginning and stop playing 30sec before the end. Is there a way to do this on rhythmbox? I know that itunes can do this, or I could use audacity but it would be easier if rhythmbox could.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the crossfade functionality in the music players. You can enable that feature in Rhythmbox also.

1. Go to the Rhythmbox menu. (It is located at the top panel in Unity panel, when Rhythmbox is current active window)
2. Select *Edit* → *Preferences* . Preference window will open
3. Select the **Playback** tab.
4. Enable the **Crossfade between tracks** option by selecting the checkbox.
5. Move the slider below **Crossfade duration** label to the right until the time value reaches 30 seconds.

You're done. See a screenshot below

[image]

Comment: I don't believe this involves crossfade at all. I also wish to skip the first few seconds of a specific song. What I hope to find is an option that I can set in the rhythmbox.xml file that tells Rythmbox to skip the first X seconds. If I find it, I'll come back here and post the answer. Otherwise, the best bet will probably be to edit the file and hack off the first X seconds with Audacity.